# How do I create a service ticket using CRM_ORDER_MAINTAIN?

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I'm trying to learn the Function Module `CRM_ORDER_MAINTAIN` and so far I managed to create a standard order with partners and their roles, however now I'm having trouble creating a service ticket with its required fields.

I tried debugging the FM when calling it from WEBUI to see what structures and tables are to be filled but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out which ones to fill and which ones are generated and don't know if I'm missing something small somewhere that's causing it not to save.

I think the error lies in this part of the code that handles Categorization, because the other code that handles adding partners worked for the standard order.

I'm not filling any GUIDS and only filling HANDLES because that's what I did for the standard order.

```
*****categorization: motive+submotive******
clear ls_input_fields.
clear ls_fieldsname.

ls_fieldsname-fieldname = 'CONC_KEY'.
INSERT ls_fieldsname INTO TABLE ls_input_fields-field_names.
ls_input_fields-ref_handle = 1."
ls_input_fields-ref_kind = gc_object_kind-orderadm_h.
ls_input_fields-objectname = 'SERVICE_OS'.

ls_subject-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_subject-ref_handle_h = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_subject-katalogart = 'Z1'.
ls_subject-codegruppe = 'ZCA00001'.
ls_subject-code = 'Z044'.
append ls_subject TO ls_osset-subject.
ls_osset-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_osset-profile_type = 'A'.
ls_osset-subject_profile = 'ZCCCAST'.
append ls_osset to ls_service_os-osset.
ls_service_os-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
append ls_service_os to it_service_os.

INSERT ls_input_fields INTO TABLE lt_input_fields.

ls_subject-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_subject-ref_handle_h = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_subject-katalogart = 'Z1'.
ls_subject-codegruppe = 'ZCA00002'.
ls_subject-code = 'Z009'.
append ls_subject TO ls_osset-subject.
ls_osset-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
ls_osset-profile_type = 'A'.
ls_osset-subject_profile = 'ZCCCAST'.
append ls_osset to ls_service_os-osset.
ls_service_os-ref_handle = ls_orderadm_h-handle.
append ls_service_os to it_service_os.

INSERT ls_input_fields INTO TABLE lt_input_fields.
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For Service OS there is a multilevel categorization up to four levels. You can check the hierarchy via `CRM_ORDER_READ` FM in parameter `ET_SERVICE_OS`.

Also, you can check the hierarchy in the below structure `CRMT_SRV_OSSET_WRK`

[image: Service OS structure]

To maintain the data for more than 2 levels of hierarchy you have to create a new ref GUID. You have to prepare and fill data to Create OS as below

```
 CALL FUNCTION 'GUID_CREATE'
      IMPORTING
        ev_guid_16 = lv_ref_guid.

ls_subject-ref_handle = '0000000000'.
ls_subject-ref_guid   =  lv_ref_guid.   " newly created ref GUID
ls_subject-cat_id = 'As per your req.'.
ls_subject-katalog_type = ''.
ls_subject-mode = 'A'.         "For creation A, for update B
" maintain other Subject parameter as per your requirement
APPEND ls_subject TO lt_subject.

" you can skip preparing Ref-Object structure if you don't want to update 
 ls_refobj-ref_guid    = lv_ref_guid.  " newly created ref GUID
 ls_refobj-product_id  = "Product ID". " optional
 ls_refobj-ref_handle  = '0000000000'.
 ls_refobj-main_object = abap_true.
 ls_refobj-mode        = 'A'.          " mode A for creating, B for update
 INSERT ls_refobj INTO TABLE lt_refobj.

ls_osset-ref_handle      = '0000000000'.
ls_osset-ref_guid        = "Header or Item GUID of Service".  
ls_osset-subject_profile = 'SERVICE'.
ls_osset-profile_type    = 'A'.        " service profile type
ls_osset-refobject       = lt_refobj.
ls_osset-subject         = lt_subject.
INSERT ls_osset INTO TABLE lt_osset.

ls_service_os-ref_guid = "Header or Item GUID of Service".
ls_service_os-ref_kind = "A or B".     " A for Header and B for Item
ls_service_os-osset    = lt_osset.
INSERT ls_service_os INTO TABLE lt_service_os.
```

Comment: is it not possible to work just with handles?

Comment: @FayçalSalhi Ref handlers are used to bind all the attributes of one order header/item together but In case of multilevel hierarchy, you've to bind using new GUID as they're not directly associated with header/Item data of service order.

Comment: it's not quite clear from your code how to set up for example 2 level categorization, like which GUIDS should be the same and which should be different..each line of IT_SUBJECT represents a category level, right?
Also when you say "Header or Item GUID of Service", I assume I have to generate a different GUID here because i'm creating this ticket for the first time, is that correct?
When debugging the CRM_ORDER_MAINTAIN call from webui, subjects have the same ref_guid, osset has a different guid, and service_os has a different guid altogether..
As you can see I'm quite confused here